# XAMPP not starting keeps 'Attempting to start MySQL app...' mysql not found in services.msc

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using the latest xampp v3.2.4 for windows and I'm attempting to start my Xampp as I do every but today its unexpectedly not starting MySQL just keep showing this log 'Attempting to start MySQL app...' and nothing happens after that. My apache is working just fine.

I read online that I could do it manually by going to services.msc and finding MySQL but there's no such thing as MySQL found in my services.msc.

Edit: I deleted my other Xampp today which was before receiving this error the xampp was named 'xampp7' and I had a problem running it long ago so I installed new xampp of the same version named 'Xampp72' which I now run every day. I'm not sure if deleting my older one was the problem or not.

Comment: search for the mysql error log and see what is wrong.

Comment: @nbk I checked, the logs are many but there's no error log reported for today's date which it should as I'm receiving this today only.

Comment: you may have installed two mysql servers and  what you see that is already started, a secnd can not be run n the same instance, As you dn't tell us which poperating system you use, you have to investigate further

Comment: @nbk I have edited my question and added new information. Please check and let me know what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: this error in mysql is most of the time a second server instance  on the same port/socket/named pipe

Comment: @nbk thank you but how can I fix this? I'm not an expert on xampp, my apologies.

Comment: uninsall mysql. lie i said in my comment, this is all diffrent for linuy or windows.and should be found with any search engie quite fast